# How to remove shutdown option in start menu but leave it on when selecting CTRL + ALT + DEL

Tags: windows-registry, shutdown, group-policy, start-menu, ctrl-alt-delete

I would like to hide/remove the shutdown option from the start menu but leave it available on CTRL + ALT + DEL.

Answer (score 0):

Use a third-party tool such as [Open-Shell Menu](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) to customize the Start menu as you see fit. Notice I've *added* options to the Shutdown menu, below; it's even easier to *remove* them.

[image: Open-Shell Menu Shutdown items]